# AngularJs- Need to control where a div will be displayed

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am creating a chat system where user speaks with a bot and I am having issue with "speaking order", the issue is a front-end issue.

Here is the HTML :

```
<section id="mood" class="col-m-12 col-12">

    <div id="botMsg" ng-repeat="botMessage in botMessages" ng-if="botMessage.available">
        <div id="separator" class="col-12">
            <div class="bot-bubble">J-M</div>
            <div class="msg bot-msg">
               {{botMessage.text}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="userMsg" ng-repeat="userMessage in userMessages">
        <div id="separator" class="col-12">
            <div class="msg user-msg">
               {{userMessage.message}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

As you can see, the botMsg div is located above userMsg. Here is the angular controller :

```
app.controller('moodController', ['$scope', '$http',function ($scope,$http){

$scope.userMessages = [];
$scope.addUserMessages = function() {

    $scope.userMessages.push({
        message : $scope.message,
        token   : "token"
    });

    $scope.message = "";

    $scope.botMessages[3].available = true;
};

$http.get('datas/data.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.botMessages = data;
})

}])
```

And the Json part where I collect bot messages

```
[
{
    "text" :"Hello Paul, comment vas-tu ? Tu as participé à la réunion Préparation lancement Commercial.",
    "available" : true
},
{
    "text" :"Je voudrais te poser trois questions.",
    "available" : true
},
{
    "text" :"Quel est ton ressenti ?",
    "available" : true
},
{
    "text" :"Super ! Pourquoi ?",
    "available" : false
}
]
```

So basically, when I type a message in the input, it triggers addUserMessages() function that push the message into an array and allow the View to display the new message (because the view crawls into the userMessages array). addUsersMessages() also set the botMessage to true with `$scope.botMessages[3].available = true;` which allo the View to render the message. But it just displays it above the new message that user just wrote, which makes sense because the botMsg div is above the userMsg div.

How can I make that so the botMessage displays below userMessage ? In other words, I need each new message to display at the end of #mood section.

Thanks

Comment: so you want that whatever message you have entered will display on first row and then bot messages right?

Comment: Right, like a proper chat would do :)
For exemple :
Botmsg
Botmsg
Botmsg
UserMsg
Botmsg

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add another property to your object, like an id or datetime stamp (would be incremental) and merge both collection to one and render them in the correct order.